# Google chrome webrequest conflict?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

Can someone please explain to me why and if it is the desired behavior that the following code WILL NOT ALWAYS alert the same value twice in a row when visiting webpages assuming a small delay in clicking "ok" on the alert box?

Usual simple extension set up with the following code in background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    alert(request.requestId);
    alert(request.requestId);
    return {};
}, {urls: ["*://*/*"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

I just cannot get this. I need the same value to pop up twice because I will be doing AJAX requests and I cannot permit myself to have variables changing behind my back with potential delays in AJAX...

If it is the desired behaviour how can I make sure this does not happen? Would closures help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rId = request.requestId;
alert(rId);
alert(rId);
```

Answer (score 4):

The most likely reason is that the pop-ups are coming from two different requests that are happening at the same time. There can be multiple requests for each underlying HTTP request, for example. Instead of using pop-ups, you can log via the `console.log()` function.

Comment: Note that console.log() still has race windows, they're just much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

what about this???

```
var rId = request.requestId.toString();
alert(rId);
alert(rId);
```